# Enable `measureUserAgentSpecificMemory` API in Chrome without cross origin isolation

Tags: javascript, performance, google-chrome, webapi

In order to use the [`performance.measureUserAgentSpecificMemory` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/measureUserAgentSpecificMemory), a site must be [cross origin isolated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/measureUserAgentSpecificMemory#security_requirements).

I want to ignore this requirement so I can temporarily test out the API on various sites I consider to be safe without worrying about cross origin isolation. Is this possible to do via some setting or command line argument that can be provided to Chrome? Or via some other easy methodology?